# error while running any python-dependent commands/programs in terminal

Tags: python, shell, runtime-error

I recently set up arch on my machine; installed python. `/usr/bin/python` was symlinked to `/usr/bin/python3` which itself is a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3.4`.
Because, I use python2.7, I went ahead and linked `python` to `python2.7`.
Now when I try to python dependent program, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3084, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3097, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 952, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==7.1.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I wish to know what's gone wrong.

Comment: You should have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297094/proper-way-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-python-on-archlinux

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wanted to understand the error itself, more than how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pip` script in `/usr/bin` is tied to Python 3.4. The small script is just a bootstrapping script to load the actual code from a module. That module is missing in Python 2.7 because you did not install `pip` for it.

Either fix the script to replace `/usr/bin/python` in the first line with `/usr/bin/python3`, or [install `pip` for Python 2.7](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Alternatively, only link `/usr/bin/python2` to Python 2.7 and leave `/usr/bin/python` to point to Python 3. It is quite likely other Arch programs rely on that being Python 3, anyway. Also see ["Proper way" to manage multiple versions of Python on archlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297094/proper-way-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-python-on-archlinux).

Comment: Yes other scripts rely on /usr/bin/python being python 3 on archlinux

Comment: so, I guess when I ran `pacman -S python-pip`, pacman installed pip for the right version of python that was default on my system(python3.4)? And if I wanted python2.7  to be the only version of python installed, I would uninstall python3.4 and reinstall every single package that depended on it?

Comment: @coder_Bibek: Yes, packages installed for Python 3.4 won't work on Python 2.7 without at least a re-install.