# Older version of Python on Manjaro (Arch Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, archlinux, manjaro

Manjaro now comes with the newest version of Python (**3.8**). However, I need an older version of Python (**3.7**) for my current projects. Is there a way to install the older version and use something like `python37` or `python38` when starting the program so that I can switch between the two versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Proper way" to manage multiple versions of Python on archlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297094/proper-way-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-python-on-archlinux)

Comment: Have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: I will try it, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try installing a specific version using `AUR`...

```sh
sudo pacman -S yay
yay -S python37
```

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python37/